# Help me find a paper/textbook on axial compressor in turboshaft engine

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, compressors

I'm trying to calculate the values of pressure, temp, speed and density of air going through an axial compressor (12-stage) a helicopter. I've read a few bachelors' thesis and papers but wasn't able to find anything particularly helpful for this task. Can anyone offer advice or, ideally, a paper/textbook with relevant information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: But some of the answers or names may never become outdated, Newton, Stevenson, Bernoulli, Pascal, Laplace, Brunel... the list goes on - who do you think of when you think of famous engineers or mathematicians well polymaths maybe a better term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good start :
Engineering Thermodynamics, Work and Heat Transfer (4th Edition). / Rogers, GFC; Mayhew, YR.

Still got mine and use it..